# Rotated image wont display in php

Tags: php, html, image, image-rotation

So i am trying to create a compass to show wind direction.

```
 Function rotate($angle) {
     $original = imagecreatefrompng("img/Arrow.png");
     $compass = imagerotate($original, $angle, 0);
     return $compass;
 }
```

That will be displayed using some html that i am echoing. The variable angle is being passed from a database. The html on the php script looks like this:

```
<img src='".rotate($row['wind_dir'])."'/>
```

The image never displays, and clearly the browser does not know where it is.

When i view the html in my browser, the above line shows as

```
<img src="Resource id #4"/>
```

and when i click on it, it navigates to a 404.

What am i doing wrong? Have i forgotten a line in the image rotation function?

EDIT:
Having tried some of the responses below, i get an image, but it only shows as a black box!

EDIT2:

Well after much fiddling, it turns out all that was needed was to the third value of `imagerotate()` to -1 as follows:

```
$original = imagecreatefrompng("img/goog.png");
$compass = imagerotate($original, $angle, -1);
imagealphablending($compass, true);
imagesavealpha($compass, true);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($compass);
imagedestroy($compass);
```

Comment: I can't imagine this code being too efficient. You're creating an image every time the page is loaded. Have you considered using CSS or JS rotation instead?

Comment: Even though you have fixed this, you should heed the words others have said. This is horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to execute the function and send header: try like below, say our php file name is rotate.php :

rotate.php

```
function rotate($angle) {
     $original = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");
     $compass = imagerotate($original, $angle, 0);
     header('Content-Type: image/png');
     imagepng($compass);
     imagedestroy($compass);
 }

if(isset($_GET['angle'])){
 rotate($_GET['angle']);
}
```

THen in your html you can call the web resource i.e you php file as:

```
<img src="url_to_rotate.php?angle=90" />
```

Also remember to sanitize the GET input before executing it.

Comment: Tried this too, image is still a black box!

Comment: Try this image and let me know your response https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png

Comment: it rotates the image successfully, but leaves a black background around the sides of the image in a square, as if it has been rotated on a black canvas.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099207/how-to-rotate-an-image-in-gd-image-library-while-keeping-transparency

Comment: Accepting your answer as it contains the majority of the code i will be using

Answer (score 2):

I posted a comment about using CSS or JS rotation instead but since then I've had a better idea.

The compass is always going to be Arrow.png in one of 360 positions.

Use a batch process in Photoshop or PHP to create 360 versions. One for each degree. Then you can just call Arrow_120.png for example for 120 degrees. You remove the issue with your existing code of creating images on the fly while avoiding compatibility issues with CSS / JS.

Comment: While i would probably use this, this is for a university assignment, and a small part of our marks come from php image handling, among other things

Answer (score 0):

The displayed image should be a image file. To achieve this you should use imagejpeg();

So basically you should have 2 php files:

1: Creates the image file using your code and imagejpeg();

```
<?php

$original = imagecreatefrompng("img/Arrow.png");
$compass = imagerotate($original, $_GET['angle'], 0);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($compass);
?>
```

2: The php file that displays the image.

```
<img src='image.php?angle=".$row['wind_dir']."'/>
```

if you want just one file you could do the following:

```
<?php

$original = imagecreatefrompng("img/Arrow.png");
$compass = imagerotate($original, $_GET['angle'], 0);

ob_start();
imagepng($compass);
$stringdata = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean(); 

$imageData = base64_encode($stringdata);
$src = 'data: image/png;base64,'.$imageData;
echo '<img src="',$src,'">';
?>
```

Comment: The image just shows as a black box now! its an improvement over nothing showing i guess...

Comment: This probably has to do with the transparency. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602263/black-background-when-rotating-image-with-php